# Disabling Multi selection in jsTree Package in R

Tags: r, shiny, jstree, multi-select

I am using jsTree in an R Shiny code for Hierarchical dropdowns and I need to disable the multi select option(Multi select is a default option in jsTree).

Please find the sample code snippet that I am using for this.

```
Region<-c("South","South","South","South","North","North","West","East","West","East")
State<-c("State1","State2","State2","State2","State3","State4","State5","State6","State7","State8")
City<-c("City1","City2","City3","City4","City5","City6","City7","City8","City9","City10")
superfundsite1=data.frame(Region,State,City)
myx10 <- apply(superfundsite1,1,function(x) paste(x,collapse = '/'))
jsTree(myx10)
```

Comment: We had to write a long java script query to achieve this.Thanks